# In my git bash command line there appears "(master)". But I am not doing commits right now. Should I flip it off some how?

Tags: command-line, git-bash

When I open git bash command line, there still appears "(master)" before the $ sign. Does that mean I forgot to log off my last commit? How do I make it go away?

Answer (score 1):

No, it indicates that the directory you are in is a Git working directory which is on the `master` branch.

If you merely want the prompt to disappear for now, switch to a directory which isn't controlled by Git. Just `cd` will switch to your home directory (though some people check their home directory into Git version control, too).

If you don't want the branch indicator at all, revert the `PS1` decorations in your Bash startup file. A common plain-jane prompt is `PS1='\w\$ '`

Comment: wow! thank you so much for responding!
so i don't have to change this? just leave it be?

Comment: That's one perfectly good way to cope. I updated the answer with some other options.